# Asp.net Mvc Form & KendoView Grid Save Toghter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

I have 2 different Tables in sql server,  Table 1 is part of asp.net mvc form & second table is part of kendo grid,  How can I save both tables once through single Button.

```
 ****Table 1 is part of asp.net mvc form as following****

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerID)
 }

 ****Table 2 is part of Kendo Grid****
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Accounting.DAL.InvoiceDetail>()
 .Name("Grid")
 .Columns(columns =>
 {

  }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're new to MVC. In MVC, every view represents a model(Domain logic class).

```
@using model Applciaton.Models.SomeViewmodel
```

//This will create a form tag. you can mention your target controller action here.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

// Form tag with action and post attribute.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm('action','controller',FormMethod.Post,new {id="formID"}))
{
  //your tables and kendo grid should be inside this form tag so you can post them to server.
  <input type="submit" value="save"/> //This will submit the form to controller action
}
```

So when your view submits data to server(controller), you can recieve it with model.

```
 [HttpPost] // Post Attribute.
 public ActionResult action(SomeViewmodel obj)//Viewmodel object from view.
 {
     //you have your kendo grid data posted from view.

     // you also have other table data and all the data you specified in model will be here.

     //Save it to db from model. call the repository from here and pass relevent data.

 }
```

Comment: the problem is that, I have 2 controllers,  InvoiceController & InvoiceDetailController & of-course 2 Models classes.

InvoiceController generate foreign key, & it is saved into second controller InvoiceDetailController ....

InvoiceController is dedicated to Html.begin.form & ...InvoiceDetailController is dedicated to KendoGrid

Comment: you cant toss controllers like that. View represents a model, controller works between model and view.